# Proving iff statements, can forward direction just be the reverse of backwards?

Tags: proof-writing

Hypothetically, could you just reverse the steps from the forward direction of the proof to do the backward direction?

For example, let's say in the forward direction, you take some value $x$ and take the square root to get $\sqrt{x}$, and then add something else to it to get $y$.

Could the backward direction be done by subtracting something from $y$, and then squaring that value to get $x$?

Comment: From the [tag:proof-writing] tag description: *"This tag should not be the only tag for a question".*

Comment: No, not always. Often one direction is easy to prove and the other direction is hard.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that not all operations can be reversed. Consider this example:

Let $x \in \mathbb{C}$. Then consider these 2 statements,

1. $x$ is a real number $\implies$ $x^2$ is a real number

This is true since the real numbers are closed under multiplication, so $x^2 = xx$ is a real number.

2. $x^2$ is a real number $\implies$ $x$ is a real number

This is false. For example, $x^2 = -1$ is a real number but there is no real number $x$ such that $x^2 = -1$. The reason you can't do the above proof backward is because $f(x) = x^2$ has no inverse function over $\mathbb{R}$.

If all your operations are reversible then yes you can do exactly what you suggested.